# How can I change behaviour of enumitem?

Tags: spacing, lists, enumitem

Document 1:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
List of items:
\begin{itemize}
\item Item one,
\item Item two,
\item Item three
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Document 2:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep}
\begin{document}
List of items:
\begin{itemize}
\item Item one,
\item Item two,
\item Item three
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Those documents look different because of `\usepackage{enumitem}` line. I want to use this package (for `\setlist[itemize]{label=--}`) but I don't want it to change spacing of my lists. How can it be done?

I found on my own that using `\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]` will do what I want. I don't want to add this parameter to every occurence of `\begin{itemize}` in my document. How can I use `\renewcommand` to do what I need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `\topsep` to 0 pt globally by

```
\setitemize{topsep=0pt}
```

With the `article` class, for example, there would be no difference. if you look at the definition of `itemize` in `mwrep.cls` , you see `\topsep` is set to 0pt by `\topsep\z@`:

```
\def\itemize{%
  \ifnum \@itemdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \edef\@itemitem{labelitem\romannumeral\the\@itemdepth}%
    \expandafter
    \list
      \csname\@itemitem\endcsname
      {\partopsep\topsep \topsep\z@ %MW
      \def\makelabel##1{##1\hfil}}%
  \fi}
```

Seeing this, you could also consider setting

```
\setitemize{partopsep=\topsep}
```

before defining 0 pt for `topsep`.

Comment: `\setitemize{topsep=0pt}` - even better that `\renewcommand` ;)